# What is executed in MPxNode and it's inheritances when a new scene is opened?

Tags: maya

I created my own deformer, and I assigned to huge resolution mesh.
At that time, if open a new scene or a existing scene file, it takes a long time to open it.
Comparing to maya's native deformer, it is significant to wasting time.
It seems that I have to do something on my deformer to clean up, but I don't know the fuction is runned when a new scene opened.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you implemented your node, it will be `deform()` and possibly `compute()`.  When the scene loads up Maya needs to prime the scene graph so all of the deformers will execute. You can verify this by adding a debug print inside those methods but that is the likely culprit.  You may find the [DG Profiler](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-C4554B37-E526-407D-B87E-A7D54C1CDCA6-htm.html) useful for spotting the culprit